# timestampdiff equivalent in JPQL (without using criteria)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc

I want to use following mysql function in JPQL:-

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, some_start_date, CURDATE());
```

Also, I do not have to use Criteria in JPA, since we are following practice of writing Named queries(JPQL). So, how can this function be written in JPQL?

Answer (score 1):

There is no timestampdiff in JPQL. Eclipse has keyword `FUNC` which allows to call DB-specific functions, like timestampdiff.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JPA 2.1 or later version, try the following JPQL:

```
select a from EntityClass a where FUNCTION('DATEDIFF', CURRENT_DATE, a.createDt) / 365 >= 1
```

The above JPQL is to retrieve all entities which have been created for more than 1 year.