# Spring Data JPA (JPQL) problem: Using TIMESTAMPDIFF function in JPA query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have the following MySQL query:

```
select p.name, sum(timestampdiff(MINUTE, r.start_time, r.end_time)) 
from ride r inner join person p on r.driver_id=p.id 
group by p.id
```

I want to write this in a JPA Query. The code below throws a NullPointerException, it does not work:

```
@RestResource
public interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<Ride, Long> {

@Query("SELECT new com.sample.dto.MyDTO(d.name, SUM(FUNCTION('TIMESTAMPDIFF', 'MINUTE', r.startTime, r.endTime))) " +
      "FROM Ride r JOIN r.driver d WHERE r.startTime BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 " +
      "GROUP BY d.id" )
  List<MyDTO> findSomething(@Param("startTime") LocalDateTime startTime,
                                   @Param("endTime") LocalDateTime endTime);

}
```

If I use DATEDIFF function, it works.

```
FUNCTION('DATEDIFF', r.startTime, r.endTime)
```

But I need the exact difference in minutes. TIMESTAMPDIFF satisfies my needs.
After failure of finding how to do this with JPA, I returned to native query but this is not good. Any alternatives?

I use the latest spring-data-jpa (2.1.3), hibernate-core:5.3.7

```
public class Ride {
  @Column(name = "start_time")
  private LocalDateTime startTime;

  @Column(name = "end_time")
  private LocalDateTime endTime;

 }
```

The goal is to find total difference between startTime and endTime (in minutes). Is there a way to do this with standard (portable) JPA?

Comment: why do you think that a native query is not good? IMHO this is a perfect fit for what you try to achieve. Native queries are ok in many situations.

Comment: Yes, here the JPA was like an unnecessary layer which caused more trouble than help to me. I'll use the native query instead of wrestling with JPQL.

Comment: @Query(value="...", nativeQuery = true)
Object[][] findSomething(..)      this Object array and mapping it is not nice. (The result is not an entity, just an aggregate function result.)

Comment: @Bhdr You may give a shot to my solution if you really want to use JPA.

Comment: Thanks Kunal. I tried, it didn't work but I'll try again when I have time.

Comment: @Bhdr Can you please tell me the error that you received? I ran a simple query using the same approach on my end and it was working.

Comment: @KunalPuri yes it works, but I also need to limit the result at the DB level. It seems JPA does not support this too. "ORDER BY blahblah  LIMIT ?3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no TIMESTAMPDIFF in JPQL.

Reference: [timestampdiff equivalent in JPQL (without using criteria)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865618/timestampdiff-equivalent-in-jpql-without-using-criteria/32896785#32896785)

So, What you can do is that you can use `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r.startTime, r.endTime)) / 60` instead of using `FUNCTION('TIMESTAMPDIFF', 'MINUTE', r.startTime, r.endTime)`

Comment: this works, but if you want to limit the results at DB level, JPA has not support it seems. For something like "ORDER BY blah LIMIT ?3" , we need native query again. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bhdr There is an alternative to LIMIT clause. Explore the `Pageable` Interface. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation/28444140. Since constructors of `PageRequest` are deprecated, Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848653/pagerequest-constructors-have-been-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

**There is no registerFunction('TIMESTAMPDIFF') in org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect.**

But registerFunction('DATEDIFF') exists.

So you cant use TIMESTAMPDIFF in jpa.

You can add custom function or use custom Dialect.

**But I suggest using unix_timestamp() instead.**

```
(function('unix_timestamp', startTime)-function('unix_timestamp', endTime))/60
```